# Charles proxY: rewrite on https does not work

Tags: https, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles Proxy to rewrite code on website, just for testing a client's site.
Rewriting works on every website, except from sites on https.

Charles has the option to choose the protocol (http or https), but that doesn't work either.
Every rewrite works well on http, not on https.
What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that the Enable SSL Proxy is ticked and that you have entered the domain in the Proxy > Proxy Settings > SSL section.

Comment: Nope that still doesn't work for me anyhow. It used to work fine last time I checked a couple of days back! Sigh!

Answer (score 3):

it is best to add a site as *
that way all https sites will show in charles.

when adding the site simply put * instead of domain.com