# Charles proxy HTTPS in Linux

Tags: linux, ssl, https, charles-proxy

I launch Charles 4.1.2 on my Linux Mint and try to map remote HTTPS request. So, I generated an SSL key like in that article
http://codeblog.shape.dk/blog/2014/01/06/custom-ssl-certificate-with-charles-web-proxy/
and added it to the SSL Proxy client and root certificates
([Charles proxY: rewrite on https does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099369/charles-proxy-rewrite-on-https-does-not-work)). But it still doesn't work.

```
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

I'm also added this certificate to the Mozilla certifications and enabled that site in always trusted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It repairs by re-adding the certificate